# var_dump not showing with style with PHP 7.3 and xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7.3

I was using `PHP 5.3` for my project in my **mac machine(OS: Mac Big sur)**. I have upgraded to `PHP 7.3` using `brew` 2 days back. Since then the `var_dump()` function showing as simple string instead of the styles one which I was getting with `PHP 5.3`.

**I have installed xdebug as per some online suggestions. Still the same display getting**

Is there any way to make `var_dump()` looks good?

When I try `php -v`, I am getting the below result which showing `xdebug` is installed.

[image]

Comment: I am on php 5 something too and have colored var_dumps. When running phpinfo(); I have one setting with var_dump `xdebug.overload_var_dump` the value is `2`.

Comment: Reading https://xdebug.org/docs/display#xdebug.overload_var_dump you need to also set `html_errors` to `On`.

Comment: What difference does it make of the format of `var_dump()`, it's a debugging tool and as long as it contains the information it should be enough.

Comment: @NigelRen, It will make the visualisation pretty. And will save some time from adding '<pre>' in code

Comment: @RolandStarke, Thanks for the hind. But still no success

Comment: If you want to format the data, then you need to do it yourself.  As I've already said - it's a debugging tool and any format/display is just convenience and not guarenteed.

Comment: What do you mean good/bad? Can you show example?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're using a web server (i.e. you are not developing a php cli script), check that you've installed xdebug not only for `php-cli`, but also for eg. `php-fpm`; you can validate that by using [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and searching for `xdebug` in the output.
2. Check [xdebug display options](https://xdebug.org/docs/display) and try adding `xdebug.cli_color = 2` to your `.ini` file:

- either to `php.ini`, at the end - [after it loads extension files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php);
- or to `xdebug.ini` if you have one; eg. in `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/`